# C# itextsharp extracting portfolio pdfs to text

Tags: itext

I am having an issue with a few portfolios they seem to not be a common format I have dealt with in the past they have only "KIDS" and they do not have "EF" only "NAMES" AND "LIMITS". PdfName.EF always returns null. How do I extract the PDF when the format is like this? The full code is below and the PDF is very large 1+ gb and has 2400+ pdfs in it.

```
static void ExtractAttachments(string file_name, string folderName)
    {
        PdfDictionary documentNames = null;
        PdfDictionary embeddedFiles = null;
        PdfDictionary fileArray = null;
        PdfDictionary file = null;
        PRStream stream = null;
        PdfArray filespecs = null;
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(folderName + "//" + file_name))
        {
            PdfDictionary catalog = reader.Catalog;

            documentNames = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(catalog.Get(PdfName.NAMES));

            if (documentNames != null)
            {
                embeddedFiles = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(documentNames.Get(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES));
                if (embeddedFiles != null)
                {
                    filespecs = embeddedFiles.GetAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);

                    if (filespecs != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; i++)
                        {
                            i++;
                            fileArray = filespecs.GetAsDict(i);
                            file = fileArray.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);

                            foreach (PdfName key in file.Keys)
                            {
                                stream = (PRStream)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(file.GetAsIndirectObject(key));
                                string attachedFileName = fileArray.GetAsString(key).ToString();
                                byte[] attachedFileBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);

                                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, attachedFileName), attachedFileBytes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filespecs = embeddedFiles.GetAsArray(PdfName.KIDS);
                        if (filespecs != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; i++)
                            {
                                filespecs.GetAsString(i);
                                PdfDictionary filespec = filespecs.GetAsDict(i);
                                //NO EF only NAMES AND LIMITS PROBLEM HERE.
                                PdfDictionary refs = filespec.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);
                                if (refs != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (PdfName key in refs.Keys)
                                    {
                                        stream = (PRStream)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(refs.GetAsIndirectObject(key));

                                        string FileName = filespec.GetAsString(key).ToString().ToUpper();
                                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                                          "D:\\WillsPDFPortfolio\\" + filespec.GetAsString(key).ToString(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate
                                        ))
                                        {
                                            byte[] attachment = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
                                            fs.Write(attachment, 0, attachment.Length);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the pdf for analysis.

Comment: Please do not share sensitive information on a public forum like Stack Overflow. While mkl is a really nice and helpful person, *you* do not know mkl, and in general you should not rely on random strangers on the internet to keep your sensitive data secret. If you get a support contract at iText Software, then your sensitive data will be treated as such, following GDPR and other relevant laws.

Comment: Instead of sharing a PDF with sensitive information, create a PDF without sensitive information that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I removed all the sensitive information from the pdf and shared that.

Comment: I removed all the sensitive information and shared it again, mkl I sent you the link again to mkl@wir-sind-cool.org see if it shows up now. Thank you.

Comment: mkl did you get the email?

Comment: I got a mail from you. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look at your example PDF it turns out that it's completely according to spec. Actually your original description *'they have only "KIDS" and they do not have "EF" only "NAMES" AND "LIMITS"'* pointed in that direction but as you also described them as *'not be a common format'* I asked for an example first.

## A Look at the Specification

***Each entry in the document name dictionary*** (`catalog.Get(PdfName.NAMES)`) ***designates the root of a name tree.** (ISO 32000-1 section 7.7.4)*

For example the **EmbeddedFiles** entry (`documentNames.Get(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES)`) maps to ***a name tree mapping name strings to file specifications for embedded file streams.** (ibidem)*

A name tree ***shall always have exactly one root node, which shall contain a single entry: either** Kids **or** Names **but not both. If the root node has a** Names **entry, it shall be the only node in the tree. If it has a** Kids **entry, each of the remaining nodes shall be either an intermediate node, that shall contain a** Limits **entry and a** Kids **entry, or a leaf node, that shall contain a** Limits **entry and a** Names **entry.** (ISO 32000-1 section 7.9.6)*

Thus, the structure you describe

> they have only "KIDS" and they do not have "EF" only "NAMES" AND "LIMITS"

is according to spec.

Let's continue in the specification:

The **Names** array ***shall be an array of the form [key<sub>1</sub> value<sub>1</sub> key<sub>2</sub> value<sub>2</sub> … key<sub>n</sub> value<sub>n</sub>] where each key<sub>i</sub> shall be a string and the corresponding value<sub>i</sub> shall be the object associated with that key. The keys shall be sorted in lexical order, as described below.** (ibidem)*

## What to Do

Thus, all you have to do is handle the **Names** entries you find in your **Kids** nodes exactly as you handle the **Names** entries you find at top level. In particular, you have to not stop there but retrieve their value as array and inspect the entries at odd offsets.

But beware, as the specs indicate, you also have to expect to find more **Kids** nodes inside **Kids** nodes (this is a tree structure of mixed, arbitrary depth after all). Thus, you should consider using recursion to extract the files.

---

I have to admit, though, that most answers one finds in respect to handling embedded files (mine included) only discuss the simple situation of a flat tree without **Kids** nodes.

Comment: Sorry to get back to this so late, do you have an example of the recursion that will work with the file I sent you?